# Test using HttpURLConnection without restricted headers

Tags: java, testing, mocking

As part of my JUnit test suite I have to test sending an HTTP request with one of `HttpURLConnection` restricted headers.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Host", host);
```

In `@BeforeTest` I can allow the restricted headers, but that won't work when the class' static initializer is executed beforehand:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
    // this won't work because HttpURLConnection has already been initialized
    System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
}
```

What would be another method of allowing the restricted headers that will work like `allowRestrictedHeaders`?

Answer (score 0):

Since we were already using `PowerMockito`, I ended up using the `Whitebox` features to modify the `restrictedHeaderSet` private static final field:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ServerTest {

    private static Set<String> restrictedHeaderSetBackup;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() throws Exception {
        Set<String> original = getRestrictedHeaderSet();
        restrictedHeaderSetBackup = new HashSet<>(original);
        original.clear();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        Set<String> modified = getRestrictedHeaderSet();
        modified.addAll(restrictedHeaderSetBackup);
    }

    private static Set<String> getRestrictedHeaderSet() throws Exception {
        return (Set<String>) Whitebox.getAllStaticFields(HttpURLConnection.class)
                .stream()
                .filter(f -> f.getName().equals("restrictedHeaderSet"))
                .findFirst()
                .get()
                .get(HttpURLConnection.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: This applies to `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`